# What is the use of controller in Directives in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Well i am new to angular and i am trying to figure out all the possible ways to work with the element. After going through some blogs, especially this [Learning Directives in angular](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx)
 i came to know that controller can be used to initialize scope, but i am not able to initialize scope inside controller, can anyone help to understand how to initialize scope inside the controller function of the directive.

This is my sample code

```
 app.directive("simple", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                transclude: true,
                template: "<div><button type='button'>{{name}}click me !!!</button></div>",
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                }
                ,
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.name = 'frog';
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: It works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/sfxxfX5bcN4ecgY5QUg3?p=preview.

Comment: i am sorry, it works thanks for your effort to help me know about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that inside a controller (any controller) you can at any point inject $scope, you do not have to worry about the initialization. That is the main purpose of a controller. and $scope is required in angularJs to perform MVC

It is good to understand that there is another place where you have access to the $scope as well, but it is not injected but rather created behind the scene and given to you. That place is inside the Link function of a directive. :)

There is another scope, and that is the $rootScope of the entire application. That particular $scope can also be injected inside services and providers (at
 run time)